# io.emit() didnot send the message to the connected clients ( in browser console)

Tags: sockets, socket.io, serversocket

Client side --> emitting the 'message' event

```
  socket.emit("message", {
  from: "Santosh",
  to: "Leela",
  text: "hey !Leela "
   });
```

//server side --. listening the event

```
   io.on("connection", (socket) => {
   console.log("a new user just connected  
   ",socket.id);


    socket.on("message", (payload) => {
    io.emit("new-message", payload);
   });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Emitting the "message " event from the client side
but server did not broadcast the message  to the connected client (in the console)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).